# For loop using user input to combine files - Using Command

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I would like to ask the user for Start & End numbers and combine only those files, for example, I have a folder with:

```
1.mp3
2.mp3
3.mp3 and so on...
```

If user answers 4 for start & 10 for end it will do:
copy /B 4.mp3 + 5.mp3 + 6.mp3 (until 10) into a file called Joined.mp3

Here's what I have so far... sorry not much...

```
set /p start="Start:"
set /p end="End:"
for %g in ("c:\temp\mp3\*.*") DO (copy /B ...)
```

I'm a quite lost here...  any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: i don't think you can "stack" arguments like that. You can `type file1.ext >> output.file` to append, but i think that malforms texty binary data. I would create a new batch file from within the old one (file redirects, looking at you), print `copy ` to it, then append each interesting file name to it, then print the last part of the command (`joined.mp3`) into it. Then you have a single-purpose bat file that does exactly what you want, run it and delete it.

Comment: `for /L %%i in (%start%,1,%end%) do ECHO %%i.mp3` should give you a start.

Comment: `… do copy /B "temp.mp3" + "%%I.mp3" "temp.mp3"`, given that you put `cd /D "C:\temp\mp3"` and `> "temp.mp3" rem/` above the `for` loop Stephan suggested…

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much!  a little tweaking and its a masterpiece... Thank you!

Comment: @echo off
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    cd /D c:\temp2\mp3
    set /p total="Total:"
    for /L %%i in (1,1,%total%) DO (
    > "song%%i.mp3" rem/
    )
    
    for /L %%i in (1,1,%total%) DO (
    
    set /p song="Song Number: "
    set /p start="Start:"
    echo !start!
    set /p end="End:"
    echo !end!
    for /L %%i in (!start!,1,!end!) DO (
    copy /B "song!song!.mp3" + "%%i.mp3" "song!song!.mp3"
    )
    )

Comment: hmm.. I'm trying to make this into CODE... please help...  (see above)  -- CTRL + K takes me to the browser address bar.... ty

Comment: Code formatting doesn't work in comments. If it solves your problem, add an answer (self-answering is encouraged on SO). If there is a problem with it, add it to the question instead and explain how it doesn't work as intended.